# Better place to download Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, download

Xcode 4.1 is a 3GB download in one shot. Their server is slow, my internet is slow, and a minor network twitch is going to make me start again from scratch.

Is there another way to download Xcode that doesn't involve 3 hours of HTTP download in one shot?

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-developer/44390183#44390183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it via a download manager so you can resume your download if it would fail or/and let someone upload it to another mirror which might be faster, or just let a friend or so download it for you and put it on a usb stick.

Comment: Use direct link from here https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and not an AppStore.

Comment: the 'resume download' feature of apple is rubbish, and fails more than it succeeds. Trying to get to xcode is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I have found googling the name of the DMG and looking for .edu sites is a good way. EDU domain sites are generally schools or universities, and have better download speeds for me at least. For xcode 3.2.6, for example, University of California in San Fransisco has the DMG here: http://www.msg.ucsf.edu/local/programs/MacOSX/
I am commenting a while after this was asked because the other answer, while valid, still gives half the download speed that this site does when I test both (not simultaneously) with `axel` or downthemall.

With `axel` I can even abort a download at one server if I think I can find better, switch to another server, and enter the same command but with a different URL to the file, and it will resume where it left off, even on a completely different server!

This is the command I ended up using:

`http://www.msg.ucsf.edu/local/programs/MacOSX/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg`

But be aware that there are risks - the usual ones, like someone having tampered with the file. Make sure the files are the right size and if you notice anything fishy, look up the DMG's checksum. Generally people have posted their checksums online in troubleshooting threads and such.